# Networking Call with Generic Decoding type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, nsurlsession, foundation

I am attempting to create a generic networking function I am looking to make an API handler which will download JSON from the network and convert theme to Swift structs that conform to the `Decodable` protocol. Currently I am using explicit types:

```
struct MyObject : Decodable {
    let id   : Int
    let name : String
}

static fileprivate func makeNetworkRequest(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping(_ error: Error?, _ myObject: MyObject?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        // handle error
        do {
            let myNewObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyObject.self, from: data!)
            completionHandler(nil, myNewObject)
        }
        catch let error {
            completionHandler(error, nil)
            return
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I am hoping to create a generic function where I can specify any data type which confirms to `Decodable` and have the data object returned in the completion handler. Something along the lines of:

```
static fileprivate func makeNetworkRequest<T>(url: URL, type: <<<Decodable Type>>>, completionHandler: @escaping(_ error: Error?, _ myObject: <<<Deocable Object>>>?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        // handle error
        do {
            let myNewObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(<<<Decodable Type>>>.self, from: data!)
            completionHandler(nil, myNewObject)
        }
        catch let error {
            completionHandler(error, nil)
            return
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

However, I can't seem to get the function parameters correct. I do not have a lot of experience working with generics. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mimic the declaration of the `decode` method of `JSONDecoder`:

```
open func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable
```

Applying the patter above to your code, the definition should be something like this:

```
static fileprivate func makeNetworkRequest<T>(url: URL, type: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ myObject: T?) -> ())
where T: Decodable
{
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        // handle error
        do {
            let myNewObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!)
            completionHandler(nil, myNewObject)
        } catch let error {
            completionHandler(error, nil)
            return
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Or you can write it in this way:

```
static fileprivate func makeNetworkRequest<T: Decodable>(url: URL, type: T.Type, completionHandler: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ myObject: T?) -> ()) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        // handle error
        do {
            let myNewObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!)
            completionHandler(nil, myNewObject)
        } catch let error {
            completionHandler(error, nil)
            return
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Worked like a charm

Comment: Can't I just use the "type" from the function param instead of T.self ?